# Substituir texto estático em diversos arquivos

Tags: php, html

Estou com um site estático e estou implementando algumas funções em php nele e uma delas é de incluir um menu em todas as páginas, sendo que o mesmo já está criado e todos os arquivos estão com ele.

O que eu quero é o seguinte: substituir todo esse código por: include menu.php

Existe alguma ferramenta em que eu possa fazer isso? Sendo que o código do menu é igual para todos os arquivos.

Comment: A função de search/replace do seu editor não resolve?

Comment: @bfavaretto eu não consegui encontrar uma função que substitua em todos os arquivos.

Comment: Experimente o [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), ele faz isso.

Comment: O Notepad++ também faz isso, o Brackets também, o comando `sed` também, as opções são várias.

Comment: Valeu demais, eu baixei o sublime aqui e consegui trocar, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço nenhuma ferramenta para fazer isso, o que você pode fazer é copiar o trecho do menu -  se for em HTML5, de`<nav>` a `</nav>`- e colocar em um arquivo .php caso o menu seja dinâmico(ou seja, necessite de processamento em back-end) ou .php ou .html acaso o menu seja estático (sem necessidade de processamento Back-end) e utilizar a tag include:

```
<?php 
   include("pasta/nomearquivo"); 
?>
```

Sendo "nomearquivo" o nome do arquivo e "pasta" caso o arquivo do menu não esteja no diretório principal e sim em um sub-diretório dentro dele, caso contrário use:

```
<?php
   include("nomearquivo");
?>
```